# Selecting records using wherebetween in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to select records having ratings from 1 to 10 using where between in laravel

Here is the query i tried, but it always shows offset errors

`$TotalResult = DB::table('summary')->whereBetween('ratings', (1, 10));`

How can i do this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: you can ref http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 errors in your Query that you constructed

1. Your limiters should be within `[your limiters here]`
2. Also you don't use `->get()` to get the results.

So your query should be

```
$TotalResult = DB::table('summary')->whereBetween('ratings', [1, 10])->get();
```

Refer [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses) to Learn more about `Where` , `WhereBetween` and Similar Clauses